# Best way to login with pop-ups in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, authentication, popup

I have a question, I have a website project for a Discord bot and I wanted to implement a popup login, but I don't think I did it correctly, if anyone can help me make it better and more secure I would be grateful.

My current code:

```
const popup = window.open(
  'http://localhost:3333/api/auth/login',
  'Discord login',
  'toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=500,height=864'
);
window.onmessage = async message => {
  if (message.origin === 'http://localhost:3333' && message.data === 'success') {
    popup?.close();

     try {
        const response = await getUser();
        resolve();
     } catch(err) {
        reject(err);
     }

  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have two separate apps? And, are you trying to do "login with other app" in the first app? Does this code work fine for you?

Comment: @AjeetShah yes, I have a server to authenticate the user, and when authentication is complete, the server redirects the user to a page with a script that posts a message in the opener window saying if the user has successfully logged in and then I just try to get the user information from the API and if successful I log the user into client side.